# Why is my application say that im missing references even though I have them?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, compilation

I'm currently learning about compiling C# code into thier own exe files.
It's really fascinating how it works!

So far I've got this really small application which should convert text being put in to a textbox to C# code which it kinda does but it keeps telling me to add references everytime I press "Build" and I dont know why.

Here is the source code:

```cs
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

           private void fakeMessageOne()
             {
                Messagebox.Show("Hello World");
             }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            CSharpCodeProvider csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", frameworkTextbox.Text } });
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, outputTextbox.Text, true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

            CompilerResults result = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceTextbox.Text);
            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                result.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => errorTextbox.Text += error.ErrorText + "\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                errorTextbox.Text = "--- Build Succeeded! ---";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors its throwing me

```
The type or namespace name 'CSharp' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'Window' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code im trying to compile inside of my application:

```cs
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fakeMessageOne()
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

And for what its worth
[here is a image of the small application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeNeu.png)

Comment: Could you show us the code you're trying to compile?

Comment: Oh sorry!  Il add it right now!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to build this?

Comment: Yes, well, to built the application, then I want to build the source code im feeding it but the application is giving me errors, added a picture.

Comment: You need to add the references to the compiler. Not to your project. The `CSharpCodeProvider ` doesn't automatically link to whichever assemblies your project is linked to.

Comment: @GooberS.Johnsson... it looks like you are using a wrong project here.Make sure you are using the right project  for example console applications , windows form applications , websites etc. You can find a lot of material online which can help you select the right project.                                            Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You should put your references in with `CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add()`

Comment: I tried that for `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp");' could not be found` but now its throwing me this 
`Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found`

Comment: Despite the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx), add the full or partial path for the metadata file of the assembly, not the _name_ of the assembly. Most assemblies consist of one file, which would therefore be the one with the assembly metadata. In any case, the .exe or .dll file, if such a file is part of the assembly, is almost always the one containing the metadata. So, add `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp");`

Comment: Oops. I meant to tack ".dll" on the end: `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");`