# Why is my application thowing me Metadata file could not be found even though I just added it?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, metadata

So I recently asked a question why my references were not added and thats because I forgot to add a snippet of code.
That snippet was this.

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp");
```

I added that snipped and now its throwing me this error instead.

```
Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found
```

Never seen any metadata errors before so this is throwing me off.

My source code

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fakeMessageOne()
        {
            if(fakeMessageCheckbox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                fakeMessage1 fkmsg = new fakeMessage1();
                fkmsg.fakeMessage();
            }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            CSharpCodeProvider csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", frameworkTextbox.Text } });
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, outputTextbox.Text, true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp");

            CompilerResults result = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceTextbox.Text);
            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                result.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => errorTextbox.Text += error.ErrorText + "\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                errorTextbox.Text = "--- Build Succeeded! ---";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is what im trying to compile in my application (not in vs)

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fakeMessageOne()
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

My old post [Why is my application say that im missing references even though I have them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737784/why-is-my-application-say-that-im-missing-references-even-though-i-have-them-c-s)

Answer (score 1):

`ReferencedAssemblies.Add()` is looking for a *file name*, so add the extension:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
```

Comment: What would be the name for CodeDom? Because I couldnt find it in the assemblies.

Comment: Would it be System.dll?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be.

Comment: That was correct, now im having issues with Metadata file 'System.Windows.Window.dll' could not be found

Comment: or well this is the error `The type or namespace name 'Window' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Isn't that just `System.Windows.dll`?